# converting string to integer in PHP but don't work ( using (int) and intval )

Tags: php, string, int

look at 2: and 3: in the image.
It should be 4, but return me '0'.

[image]

Comment: What's the exact value of `$UO2`? Do a `var_dump($UO2)`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi: As you can see on the screenshot "4" (as string).

Comment: Yes, I can see. But I can also see that the text goes bold on the first line. So I suspect there is something else in the value which makes int casting to return 0.

Comment: @GergoErdosi - very good catch! It can well be some HTML tags +1. Say you have something like `$UO2 = " <div>3<b>";` then the casting will return `0`

Comment: @GergoErdosi: I didn't think about that! The use of strip_tags() might be the answer.

Comment: It would be much more useful if instead of providing a screenshot, you showed the underlying code as text.

Comment: Please don't post code as images - just paste in your code and use the code button to preformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is how you are using Simple HTML DOM.

You are exploding `$element[2]`, which is the second `<b>` tag in the document. But it is not a string, it is an object representing the DOM element.

If you are trying to get the content of the  tag you should use

```
$element[2]->innertext
```

Comment: Pleased to see that my answer helped you. If my answer solved your problem click the big checkbox to accept it, so that everyone knows that the problem has been solved :)